# How to push back onto a queue using nodes?

Tags: c++, debugging, queue, nodes

I have the following node

```
struct Node
{
  Node(int s, std::vector<uint8_t> d) : score(s), data(d){};
  int score;
  std::shared_ptr<Node> left = nullptr;
  std::shared_ptr<Node> right = nullptr;
  std::vector<uint8_t> data;
};
```

And currently, I am reading in a bunch of strings from a file and pushing that back onto a vector of strings. I then go ahead and create a queue, `std::queue<Node> myQueue`. I then use a for each loop and for each item in my sequences, I convert it using an enum that contains the values I need them to convert to. I then create a new shared_ptr, pass it a score of 0 and insert the newly converted vector. However, when I try to compile it, I get the following error:

```
error: no matching function call to 'std::queue<Node>::push(std::shared_ptr<Node>&)'
```

I'm kind of stuck as I am not sure why it won't compile as this seems pretty straight forward.

```
enum class Items : uint8_t
{
  A = 0x00,
  T = 0x01
};

std::vector<uint8_t> convert(std::string &s)
{
  std::vector<uint8_t> temp;
  for (int i = 0; i < s.size(); ++i)
  {
    switch(s[i])
    {
      case 'A':
        temp.push_back(uint8t_t(Items::A));
        break;
      case 'T':
        temp.push_back(uint8t_t(Items::T));
        break;
    }
  }
  return temp;
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<std::string> sequences;

    std::ifstream file("strings.txt");
    std::string line;   
    while (std::getline(file,line))
    {
    sequences.push_back(line); 
    }

    std::queue<Node> myQueue;

    for(auto && e : sequences)
    {
        std::vector<uint8_t> strings = convert(e);
        auto makeNode = std::make_shared<Node>(0,strings);
        myQueue.push(makeNode);
    }

}
```

I do not know what I am doing wrong, I think this is the correct way to construct a queue of Nodes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You try to push an object Node to a queue of std::shared_ptr of an object Node. The pointer is not the object.

The correct way to create your queue is:

```
 std::queue<std::shared_ptr<Node>> myQueue;
```

Comment: Thank you! I cannot believe I missed that.